# JSON jolt null value added to a nested array after transformation

Tags: json, transform, apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

I have an issue with the JSON jolt transformation, please consider the following case,
I have tried different versions of jolt library too.

input json:

```json
{
  "id": "b08a2c93-f59e-4f54-8e16-2f1c4345b53b",
  "equipment": [
    {
      "number": "S765769",
      "type": "40 DRY"
    },
    {
      "number": "N5765769",
      "type": "20 DRY"
    }
  ]
}
```

Jolt Spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "equipment": {
        "*": {
          "number": [
            "CTN[&1].IDT",
            "CTN[&1].CTN[&1].IDT"
          ],
          "type": "CTN[&1].CTN[&1].TYP"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Output Json:

```json
{
  "CTN": [
    {
      "IDT": "S765769",
      "CTN": [
        {
          "IDT": "S765769",
          "TYP": "40 DRY"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "IDT": "N5765769",
      "CTN": [
        ** null **,
        {
          "IDT": "N5765769",
          "TYP": "20 DRY"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see in the output, in the second CTN array object, the first element is null !
How do we get rid of that null so that the output will be like this

Required output

```json
{
  "CTN": [
    {
      "IDT": "S765769",
      "CTN": [
        {
          "IDT": "S765769",
          "TYP": "40 DRY"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "IDT": "N5765769",
      "CTN": [
        {
          "IDT": "N5765769",
          "TYP": "20 DRY"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can squash that null out adding an extra step to your spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "equipment": {
        "*": {
          "number": [
            "CTN[&1].IDT",
            "CTN[&1].CTN[&1].IDT"
          ],
          "type": "CTN[&1].CTN[&1].TYP"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]
```